# SWF file from website crashes computer on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS but not Win 8

Tags: linux, windows-8, firefox, memory, ubuntu-12.04

If I visit the website (with Firefox 26.0 or Chrome) `http://betway.com/sports-betting` then on `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS` (on a brand new Lenovo S540, Haswell i7, 8Gb RAM, 10gb linux swap-drive), and use `System Monitor` to watch my memory, I see it quickly rise to 7.8gig then the swap drive use start to rise, until I can no longer move mouse or keyboard (only `ALT+SYSRQ+R+S+E+I+U+B` can save me).

Yet, visiting on Windows 8 on the same machine, no probs and the memory/cpu usage hardly moves above baseline. Similarly, if I boot with the `Ubuntu 12.04.3` live usb I see no issues when visiting the page. I've deduced (using noscript) that it is only when a certain flash section of the webpage loads that the crash occurs (although other flash pages seem fine when visited, e.g. Youtube.com or BBC iPlayer).

**edit:** In fact, if I grab the `.swf` file: `wget images.lvnassist.net/images/flash/betting/bw_sportsbanner_live.swf` then open it with firefox this alone is enough to cause the crash. I've scanned with `clamscan` and no viruses seen..

**edit2:** I tried this with Virtual Machine (VMWare) running `Ubuntu 13.10` and it caused the same crash (luckily in the VM the memory is restricted and the crash just results in the "The Abode Flash plugin has crashed. Reload the page to try again" error after a few minutes. Using `top` I see that the `plugin-container` module resources sky rocket, and I eventually get a "plugin-container crashed with SIGSEGV" error.

What could be causing this? I'd be happy to post any logs etc...What should I be looking for in order to identify the root cause?

(I originally thought it might have been the proprietary `fglrx` drivers that seem to be necessary for my Hybrid Radeon HD 8670M card as I'd noticed another few irregularites, but if I switch back to the built in intel GPU with the AMD Catalyst control centre, then reboot, I still get exactly the same crash behaviour, so maybe that rules this theory out?)

Comment: is it the same version of Firefox in both OS? Have u tried a different browser in Linux like Chrome or Opera?

Comment: Yes same version of FF, and I just tried Chrome (clean install, no plugins) also crashed in same way...

Comment: My next step would be to try a live CD/DVD of a newer version of Ubuntu and see if the problem persists

Comment: I can give that a go. I've got a hunch it may have something to do with the `Radeon HD 8 series` graphics card on this laptop and the proprietary fglrx driver that was installed...but I could be wrong, and I'm not sure how to test that theory.

Comment: you could boot to a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Live CD without the proprietary fglrx driver as see if it persists. If it does it may be something with 12.04. If it doesn't it is likely the driver.

Comment: I tried that, see post. Maybe it is the GPU. Is there an easy way I can turn off the discrete Radeon GPU in Ubuntu to just use the intel to see if that fixes things?

Comment: I used AMD Catalyst Control Center to switch to the intel GPU, so my `lshw -C video` now just shows the Haswell integrated graphics...after a reboot the troublesome website still causes the crash. OK...maybe it's something else than the GPU, not sure?